# Confirmar antes de registrar un formulario en PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Holas, estoy creando un formulario de registro que quisiera que confirme (SI o NO) antes de hacer el submit. Mi código es el siguiente pero no funciona correctamente, se muestra la ventana para confirmar pero en tan solo unos segundos sin hacer clic en nada, se envía solo el formulario, es decir se ejecuta el submit y obviamente lo que quisiera es que espere la confirmación de SI o NO para registrar:

```js
function ConfirmarRegistro(){
  alertify.confirm('Confirmar Movimiento', '¿Seguro de registrar este movimiento?', function(){
   return true;
  }
  , function(){
      return false
  });
}
```

```html
<form id="frmMovimiento" name="frmMovimiento" action="?view=movimientos&mode=add" onsubmit="return ConfirmarRegistro();" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  <fieldset> 
  ...
  <p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registrar Movimiento</button>
  </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes prevenir que se haga el submit en el formulario hasta que se cumpla con determinada condición.
Puedes agregar un evento que estará atento a cuando se haga **submit** en tu formulario.

tu script:

```
   document.getElementById('my-form').addEventListener('onsubmit', function (event) { 
      event.preventDefault(); 
      my_func(); 
      }); 

      var my_func = function () { 
        //HACER ALGO 
        }
```

Y cuando la respuesta sea sí puedes hacer que se haga submit de la siguiente manera:

```
document.getElementById("tu_form").submit();
```

Espero haberte ayudado. Suerte!

Answer (score 1):

efectivamente me hacía falta controlar el evento submit. Con la siguiente función pude solucionarlo. Muchas gracias por el apoyo.

```js
document.getElementById('frmMovimiento').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    alertify.confirm('Confirmar Movimiento', '¿Seguro de registrar este movimiento?', function(){
      alertify.success('Ok');
      document.getElementById('frmMovimiento').submit();
      }
      , function(){
      alertify.error('Cancel');
      });
   });
```